# Create many simple products with similar attributes at once

Tags: admin, configurable-product

I'm having major product overload just doing 1 out of 99 and I'm not even done yet.

We have a product that comes in **99** flavors. Each of the 99 flavors have the **same attributes**. We have **5** bottle sizes, **6** nicotine levels, and **4** VG/PG levels. It basically makes a **TON of "simple products"** for just this one flavor alone.

Is there any plugin that can do it all the attributes at once (like on one page) or some kind of "generator" that can make a text file and just load that?

Answer (score 1):

**Here are solutions without any extension:**

To generate the simple products: Create one with all attributes, export it as CSV with the ImportExport feature, copy and paste the row 99 times, make your changes in the columns for sku and your configurable attributes, save, and import again.

If you already created all the simple products, with the "quick create" feature from the configurable product, you can use the "Update Attributes" mass action in the product grid to set the same values for any attribute to a bunch of products.

Comment: Using CSV will probably mean one at a time per file. Currently I'm at 83 simple products and not done yet. Then I'll probably have to manually upload the pictures to the "main" ones individually.

Comment: The CSV can contain as many products as you want. You can also import images (place them in `media/import` to do so) but since you did not explain how images come into play, I cannot tell you more.

Comment: The image part is manageable. I can just do that on the configurables.

The only issue with CSV is that I'll have maybe 8,000-10,000 products to have on that one file. Pretty unmanageable.